# Cannot find module 'eslint-config-defaults/configurations/eslint'

Tags: c#, node.js, visual-studio-code, eslint

I am new to working with the light version of Visual Studio Code and for the life of me I cannot figure out how to resolve this error.

I've tried to pull in any type of file the even closely resembles the terms .eslint but i always get this error. I am sure it is a config error but I do not know how to work with the config just yet.

Any suggestions?

I am taking a Node.js course and they are using this light version and i would like to use it as well because it is somewhat faster for taking classes and so on.

**Error**

```
Cannot find module 'eslint-config-defaults/configurations/eslint'
```

[image: eslint Error - Look at the very top of the enviroment]

Answer (score 28):

You will have to install eslint-config-defaults and other related modules.
Fire up a Shell and execute:

```
$ npm install --save eslint-config-defaults
```

Note: You might also be prompted with other errors after installing the above module. So, you have to install those modules as well.

Comment: something like eslint-plugin-react

Comment: `--save` or `--save-dev`? I would use `--save-dev`